# Chromium Unable to reproduce html video / mp4 video

Tags: html, video, chromium

Today I'm facing a strange issue with Chromium.

When I try to reproduce a video like this:

[Example Video](https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aDxqxGd_460sv.mp4)

[image: Video not Working]

It doesn't work on Chromium but does on Firefox. The strange thing is that it was working well but stopped working.

I haven't changed the Chromium version but tried restoring default settings and didn't work.

Any ideas?

I am currently using Chromium Version 67.0.3396.87 on Debian 9.

Youtube videos work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is the website itself:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aDxqxGd_460sv.mp4"
```

So I will leave it alone until developers fix it.